# How can I match a list of .NET type for null in a F# record type?

Tags: c#, f#, pattern-matching

I have a class defined in C#:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Then I define a record type in F# with a method returning a new object:

```
type Bar =
    {
        FooList: Foo list
    }
    member this.FromBarList(barList: string list) =
        let fooListNotNull =
            match this.FooList with
            | [] -> []
            | _ -> this.FooList |> List.filter (fun x -> (List.contains x.Bar barList ) )
        {
            FooList = fooListNotNull
        }
```

Since the type 'Bar' will be used in C# code, the property `FooList` can be null, and I'd like to check for it. But I'm getting the error:

> The type 'Foo list' does not have 'null' as a proper value

Despite I find this type of matching in docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/values/null-values

How can I match `null` correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to make a null F# list within F# and presumably in C# too:

```
let nullList = Unchecked.defaultof<int list>
```

You can check for null but you need to box it first:

```
match box nullList with
| null -> []
| _ -> nullList
```

Here's a generic function to do this for any value:

```
let defaultNull defaultValue x =
    match box x with
    | null -> defaultValue
    | _ -> x
```

This is how you would use it in your case:

```
nullList |> defaultNull []
```

Answer (score 3):

`'a list` is an F# type, hence not nullable. I believe there is some implicit conversion here, but the actual type of a C# list is `System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>`, which is nullable. It is conveniently aliased as [`ResizeArray<'T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.resizearray%5B't%5D-type-abbreviation-%5Bfsharp%5D) in F#.

Replace `Foo list` with `ResizeArray<Foo>`, then the snippet you provide should at least compile.

Comment: ``System.Collections.Generic.List<'a>`` has a shorthand in F#: ``ResizeArray<'a>``. Furthermore, an F# list can be used in C# by accessing it as an ``IEnumerable<'a>``. If you need to use ``'a list``, you can test for null by casting to ``obj`` (with reference types this is essentially a no-op on the machine level). I believe modern F# versions have a built-in function for that but if not, you can easily write your own: ``let isNull (x : 'a when 'a : not struct) = match box x with null -> true | _ -> false``

Comment: @dumetrulo Ah, TIL. I've updated the question to mention `ResizeArray`. It might be that the value originates from F# - the question doesn't say - but if it's passed around as `IEnumerable<Foo>` in C#, you'd have to deal with it as a `Foo seq` when coming back, not a `Foo list`. In either case, `isNull` should work though.

Comment: @glennsl I updated my example because it was not complete. As you can see I need the type to be list to perform operations on it